# Site working in FF not in IE, Built with iframes

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iframe, redirect

I have a site, that i built through iframes, but i cant seem to use it with IE.
For safety resons i cannot give access to it, but ill explain wehat the problem is.
First of all i was forced to do it through iframes due to the webserver didnt support .net.
Heres how it looks:

http://ipdg.se/order.htm

So far so good, an iframe working good. But when i try to log in the problem starts.
If FF it goes smoothly, but in ie, it doesnt happen anything(Would normally be redirect to the same page but with session variables and showing other content) i dont know what causes this. but either IE cannot do response.redirects, or there is a problems with the iframe.. or both.

It works in alla major browsers except for internet explorer!

Comment: Please confirm which version(s) of IE you're having problems with.

Comment: is there any way of doing what you want without i frames?

Comment: Both 7/8, dont know a bout 6... but who cares about 6 ? :(

Comment: Well, its already built, and i belive iframes was the best solution, if it hadnt been for IE!

Comment: Before you get too far into a solution, I would suggest downloading and testing in a few other browsers; Opera, Google Chrome, Apple Safari (in this case testing Chrome and Safari seperately is warranted - the issues are not in the rendering engine). Frames create a lot of questions about safety and standards ambiguity, to which each browser has its own answers. Fixing the 'problem' in IE may create or worsen problems in other browsers (for example watch out for caching issues when Safari handles frames).

Comment: I tried it with 2 different versions of both.. Only IE that doesnt work correctly -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a previous poster said. the problem is with IE and its security check, therefore. Using server.transfer got it working.

response.redirect doesnt redirect directly to the page, it communicates with the client browser before the redirect. therefore the browser has a chance to stop the request(Lame IE).
but server.transfer doesnt do that and goes around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some time back there was a problem like this... the iframe tag was

```
<Iframe src="order.php" width="450" height="650"></Iframe>
```

The solution was to change the src from order.php to order.html... That may not be possible in your case, but it appeared that there was an IE security setting that prohibited the dynamic page from loading.